# Restcomm jSS7 mangement console cannot create any sctp server, sccp rule

Tags: restcomm

I would like to ask for help, i have installed the Resctomm SS7Stack. I can  open the GUI but i can't add a Sctp server ,Sccp rule even i can't sign out.I tried using a sheel command and it's working. My OS is Ubuntu 16.04.
Thanks in advance.